# MobaXterm is there a way to disable copy on select?

Tags: clipboard, text-editing, mobaxterm

I am using SSH in MobaXterm, is there a way to prevent automatic "copy" when you select some text (e.g. in gedit), or with the mouse ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In MobaXterm, go to Settings -> Configuration -> X11 -> X11 Settings -> Clipboard -> "disable primary".

As the tooltip says:

> Define the way MobaXterm will handle **copy/paste** operations between X11 applications and Windows applications:
>
> - **diabled**: copy/paste from and to X11 applications will not work
> - **enabled**: copy/paste from and to X11 applications will work
> - **disable primary**: selecting some text will not automatically copy it, only explicit requests to copy text will be handled.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzyUa.png)

Comment: doesn't work. selecting is still copying